# Rails Counter Cache with Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, counter-cache

I have a `Account` model with 3 attachments, using Active Storage, `has_many_attached :attachments`.

I want to know how many attached files the account has, the most efficient way (aka no joins)

The only solution I found is
`Account.last.attachments.count` or `.size`, but it makes two query: one for the account and one using active_storage_attachments table.

Is there a way to counter cache the number of attachments?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

Of course I can set up my own database field and count it, I want to know if there is some default

**EDIT**

I tried to do `has_many_attached :attachments, counter_cache: true`, but it gives an error

Comment: https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/06/19/activerecords-counter-cache.html should help you out

Comment: Hey @Mark, thank you for your response. Unfortunately that article does not talk about Active Storage solution. I know how to use counter cache, the problem is with ActiveStorage

Comment: Sorry I should read more carefuly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue with a model that had 7 file attachments, which I needed to count using counter cache instead of the a database query. The trick is that you have to specify counter cache reference in the child model, which has the `belongs_to :ParentModel` - `ActiveStorage::Attachment` in my case.
`ActiveStorage::Attachment` is a 'behind-the-scenes' model of Rails so I monkey patched it. But instead of implementing counter cache by adding `counter_cache: :true` I decided to implement it through callbacks. I created a module for the `ParentModel` with following structure:

```
module ParentModel::ModuleName
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class ActiveStorage::Attachment
    require 'active_record/counter_cache'

    before_create :after_create_action, if: :record_parent_model?
    before_destroy :after_destroy_action, if: :record_parent_model?

    def after_create_action
      ParentModel.increment_counter(:attachments_count, record_id, touch: true)
    end

    def after_destroy_action
      ParentModel.decrement_counter(:attachments_count, record_id, touch: true)
    end

    def record_parent_model?
      record_type == 'ParentModel'
    end
  end
end
```

And I created a migration to add `:attachments_count` column to the ParentModel as in case of a straight forward counter cache implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try to use CounterCache ?
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html

Comment: You suggest to do a migration creating a new db field and use increment / decrement_counter when a new attachment is added / removed?

Comment: Why not ? You can increment your field when you upload an attachment, and decrement the field when you delete it ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I wanted to know if there are any default solutions, but probably this is the only way